# sqldf dates mismatch in R

Tags: r, sqldf

I am trying to summarize the value by day and name and after that day column gives wrong day as number

```
 Day      name  value
02-09-2015  1   2
02-09-2015  2   4
02-09-2015  5   6
02-09-2015  6   8
02-09-2015  6   10
02-09-2015  7   12
02-09-2016  13  14
02-09-2016  14  16


library(lubridate)
df$Day <- mdy(df$Day)

tp=sqldf("select Day ,name ,avg(value) as value from df group by Day,name")

Day   name  value     Correct_day_num
16475   1   2         42249
16475   2   4         42249
16475   5   6         42249
16475   6   9         42249
16475   7   12        42249
16840   13  14        42615
16840   14  16        42615
```

Please suggest any modifications

Comment: I don't know how it is the 'Correct_day_num` as `as.integer(df$Day)#
[1] 16475 16475 16475 16475 16475 16475 16840 16840`

Comment: Related, possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29288539/how-to-convert-an-integer-value-to-datetime-in-sqldf-in-r

Comment: Can you add output of `dput(df1)` to your post? I can't reproduce your sqldf output.